# MongoDB, how to update a part of an array only?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a document in MongoDB which holds some meta info like the date updated and the _id, and an array of addresses.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "4e73a30466ca1a1f56000001"
    },
    "updated": 1316215062,
    "address": [
        {
            "street": "Rotenturmstrasse 8",
            "postcode": "1020",
            "phone": "Vienna",
            "altitude": -1,
            "geolocation": [
                "11.367464",
                "47.204876"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now there could be multiple addresses. I am creating an object for an address which needs to be updated and saving it to the database. This is what the new object to be inserted looks like:

```
new_object = {
    :_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e73a30466ca1a1f56000001'), 
    :updated=>1316215099, 
    :address=>[
        nil, 
        nil, 
        {
            :street=>"Reumannplatz 8", 
            :postcode=>"1020", 
            :phone=>"Vienna", 
            :altitude=>-1, 
            :geolocation=>[
                "12.367464", 
                "48.204876"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Upon calling `db.venues.save(new_object)` what I would like the document to end up looking like is:

```
{
    :_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e73a30466ca1a1f56000001'), 
    :updated=>1316215099, 
    :address=>[         {
            "street": "Rotenturmstrasse 8",
            "postcode": "1020",
            "phone": "Vienna",
            "altitude": -1,
            "geolocation": [
                "11.367464",
                "47.204876"
            ]
        },

        nil,

        {
            :street=>"Reumannplatz 8", 
            :postcode=>"1020", 
            :phone=>"Vienna", 
            :altitude=>-1, 
            :geolocation=>[
                "12.367464", 
                "48.204876"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead it overwrites the entire array and ends up like this:

```
{
    :_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e73a30466ca1a1f56000001'), 
    :updated=>1316215099, 
    :address=>[
        nil, 
        nil, 
        {
            :street=>"Reumannplatz 8", 
            :postcode=>"1020", 
            :phone=>"Vienna", 
            :altitude=>-1, 
            :geolocation=>[
                "12.367464", 
                "48.204876"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the way to do it? I am trying to avoid multiple queries. Would it make things easier if  the address array in the database was a hash instead?

Comment: what are those `nil`s? if these are specific addresses you shouldn't store them in an array.

Comment: I have an array of multiple addresses. But I wan't only a particular one to be updated. I was optimistically hoping that Mongo would be clever to insert the new data, and not overwrite old data with nil. I am not convinced that an array is the way to go, however if I stored it in a hash, then the keys would be incremental integers again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter the data use mongodb [modifiers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations).

In this case, you want to [$push](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) a new value to the array.

Comment: What happens if I want to update an single existing value in the address array without touching the others? The documentation is really scarce on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need in this case is [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/), which would append the new address objet to the list.

To update a single record on the array is a little difficult, but depending on the case, [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) might handle it.